# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate is not accepting switch case values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, switch-statement

I was trying to create a single function to update different types of options in Mongoose model and encountered this strange behavior.
Here's what I was trying to do.

```
module.exports.updateUser = function(id, action, status, callback) {
const query = {
    _id: id
};

let field = '';
switch (action) {
    case 'download':
        field = 'download_permission';
        break;
    case 'upload':
        field = 'upload_permission';
        break;
    case 'view':
        field = 'view_permission';
        break;
    case 'edit':
        field = 'edit_permission';
        break;

}
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
        field: status,
        last_updated: moment().format('llll')
    }
}, callback);

};
```

Now, if I try something like :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
$set: {
    'edit_permission': status,
    last_updated: moment().format('llll')
}
}, callback);

};
```

It actually updates the document in the mongodb.
Can someone explain me why second works and not the first (doesn't update the document). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES6, you can define [computed keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) using bracket notation.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
        [field]: status,
        last_updated: moment().format('llll')
    }
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
       problem ------->>>>field<<<<<: status,
        last_updated: moment().format('llll')
    }
}, callback);
```

The field object param will not resolve to the value of your variable `field`.

This should fix it:

```
const setStatement = { 
    last_updated: moment().format('llll') 
};
setStatement[field] = status;

User.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: setStatement
}, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can have a variable as a key... If you put it that way... the variable itself becomes a string and becomes the key... the value of the variable wont appear in key's place